# PHP split array on last occurence of specific word before delimiter

Tags: php

I have array like this:

```
$array = "this is; some text delimiter; and brackets {here} some; sometext; text; again brackets {title} are here";
```

And I need to split it on last occurence of ";" before "{" and than on "}". Like this:

```
Array(
  [0] => this is; some text delimiter;
  [1] => and brackets {here}
  [2] => some; sometext; text;
  [3] => again brackets {title}
  [4] => are here
)
```

Can anybody suggest me how could I do this?

Comment: Show us your code and the specific part where you are stuck so that the community can actually help you instead of having to guess what part you are having problems with.

Comment: I would be happy to do that, but actual code is more than hundred lines, so I wrote just an example. I can pull out anything from curly brackets, I can split on curly brackets or ; but what I need is split on first occurence of ; if you look behind from { and than split on } (that part I know how to do)

Comment: If it "is more than hundred lines" isolated the actual problem code and share that. We expect a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @PeeHaa, i think that question is clear (see example output), no need for code (because there is no code for what OP wants, yet). So, codexy wants to find last occurence of ; BEFORE brackets.

Comment: That's... not how SO works...

Comment: @PeeHaa, well... in theory... :)

Comment: Correct, in theory. In practice it has become a "halp gimme codez site" because of people feeding the downwards spiral.

Comment: Why does `this is; some text delimiter;` not form two entries in your result array? Also, initially you have a *string*, not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is my try:

```
$array = "this is; some text delimiter; and brackets {here} some; sometext; text; again brackets {title} are here";

$re = '/((?<=})\s)|(;(?=[^;]+{))/';
$split = preg_split($re, $array);

print_r($split);
```

Regex explanation: https://regex101.com/r/jRwu1e/1

So, this should find every white space followed by closing bracket and every semicolon before bracket, and split strings by it.

Demo: https://eval.in/699668
P.S. if you need closing semicolons (in output), little mod is needed, but this could be starting point...

EDIT: one more positive lookbehind to keep semicolon in output:

```
$re = '/((?<=})\s)|((?<=;) (?=[^;]+{))/';
```

https://eval.in/699671

EDIT 2:
Regex explanation, by request:

First group `((?<=})\s)` matches spaces behind brackets, with `positive lookbehind`:

1) https://regex101.com/r/FbC2hG/1

Second group `((?<=;) (?=[^;]+{))` should match spaces behind semicolons, but semicolons which are placed BEFORE opening brackets (last occurence before brackets, so previous occurences should be skipped; negated character class `[^;]`, if that is right terminology?). 
I've used `positive lookbehind` and `positive lookahead`:

2) https://regex101.com/r/H8rU5i/2

Together, these two regexes should split string on desired places:

3) https://regex101.com/r/H8rU5i/3

Comment: I didn't downvote, but some people downvote when you answer bad questions, because it encourages more people to write bad questions.

Comment: @Barmar, i guess. But, question wasn't so bad (it is quite interesting, imho), after all. There was no attempts (and i am sure that plenty of highly upvoted questions doesn't have OP code attempt)s, but problem is 1) well described 2) example output was clear... if there are just more such questions here... :)

Comment: I did not downvote also, but somebody downvoted my question also. I thought I was clear enough, I couldn't show actual code because it is too long, and I did not see any purpose to show attempts as they were not even close to be correct. Anyway, thank you, @sinisake. this is great solution, I was able to implement this is my code with just minor edits.

Comment: @sinisake if you can explain more about this regular expression that would be great answer.

Comment: @Faisal, thanks. As soon as I get back to PC, I will do it.

Comment: @Faisal, i've added 'explanation'. Please keep in mind that i am not regex master, by any means (learning regex, too, and try to avoid them, whenever is possible:)), and that's best explanation i can give at the moment. Also, i am sure that some regex guru could make better regex (or provide different, more flexible approach), but it seems that this one is working, too. :)